# How to calculate specific date based on the day of the week?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form that is due on the first Tuesday of each month.
I would like to find a way to automatically populate the due date based on the current date, by showing the date of the next upcoming first Tuesday.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the specific calculation to do this in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

```
=DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Today.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays("TueMonSunSatFriThuWed".IndexOf((DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Today.Day).AddMonths(1).DayOfWeek + "").Substring(0, 3))/3)
```

This calculation leverages `DateTime.DayOfWeek` to determine the day of the week, converts this to an offset by looking up the day of the week in this text value `TueMonSunSatFriThuWed`, and adds the corresponding days to the first day of the month.